# Maven Tycho cannot satisfy plugin dependency

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, tycho

I have an eclipse product which I am configuring from a target definition.
I define the `CDT` version `9.4.3` to be used.

```
<location...>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.feature.group" version="9.4.3.201802261533"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.gdb.feature.group" version="9.4.3.201802261533"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.gdb.source.feature.group" version="9.4.3.201802261533"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.build.feature.group" version="9.4.3.201802261533"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.build.source.feature.group" version="9.4.3.201802261533"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.debug.feature.group" version="9.4.3.201802261533"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.debug.source.feature.group" version="9.4.3.201802261533"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.dsf.feature.group" version="9.4.3.201802261533"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.gnu.dsf.source.feature.group" version="9.4.3.201802261533"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.native.feature.group" version="9.4.3.201802261533"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.native.source.feature.group" version="9.4.3.201802261533"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.platform.feature.group" version="9.4.3.201802261533"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.platform.source.feature.group" version="9.4.3.201802261533"/>
<unit id="org.eclipse.cdt.sdk.feature.group" version="9.4.3.201802261533"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/"/>
</location>
```

In eclipse the target loads succesfully, but when I try to build the product with maven tycho ( running `mvn clean install`), it complains a bout a missing plugin dependency `com.google.gson`:

```
[ERROR] Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: PLUGIN.id 4.5.5.5
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: org.eclipse.cdt.core 6.4.0.201802261533 requires
'bundle com.google.gson 0.0.0' but it could not be found
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: PLUGIN.id 4.5.5.5 depends on: com.domain.plugin.feature.feature.group [1.0.0,1.0.1)
[ERROR]   Cannot satisfy dependency: com.domain.plugin.feature.feature.group
 1.0.0.qualifier depends on: org.eclipse.cdt.core 0.0.0
[ERROR]
[ERROR] See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Dependency_Resolution_Troubleshooting
for help.
[ERROR] Cannot resolve dependencies of MavenProject: com.domain.plugin:com.domain.plugin:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ D:\Dev\Sources\src\plugin\plugins\com.domain.plugin\pom.xml: See log for details -> [Help 1]
```

How can I provide this dependency and why it's not collected directly from the `eclipse oxygen p2 repo`?

Comment: Adding manually the missing plugin  in the tagret definition works and I have another error with another plugin which is missing, I assume I will have to manually add all the deps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think **com.google.gson** is not part of the eclipse oxygen standard repo since it's a 3rd party lib. Eclipse orbit repo maintains these libraries.

```
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="false" includeMode="planner" includeSource="false" type="InstallableUnit">
  <unit id="com.google.gson" version="0.0.0"/>

   <repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20170919201930/repository"/>
</location>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Kondal, I took me quite a lot to figure it out last week. I found the plugin also in the eclipse oxygen repository and I added it manually to the target definition ( also the following 5 required plugins). It's not a nice solution, because I'm expecting to have it all in one place and not to add each external plugin required by a feature by hand, but as long as it works, I'm fine with it.